# How to suspend a silent oberserver from Facebook account?

Tags: passwords, facebook, account-lockout

A friend of mine told me about the following problem: She used to login on Facebook on a computer of her boyfriend. After they broke up she recognized that he was able to login to her account from his computer.

Of course she then changed her password, but still he is able to login via *any* device (smartphone, computer, etc.). She can see that in her active sessions log (though he denies that it was him). He does it as a kind of a silent observation, he wants to know where she is, who she spents time with etc.

She now is not only very angry about her "stolen privacy" but since she doesn't know what else he is capable of doing next..

**So my questions basically are:**

- How is it possible to get access to an account even if the password has changed?
- Is it likely that other accounts (email, skype etc.) are compromised as well (even if not used on another computer)?
- How to answer this "silent attack", i.e. regain control and completely suspend him from her account(s)? What can you do to block it?

Again, changing the password didn't help!

Any help is appreciated!

(Please correct tags, edit question etc if not clear enough)

Comment: In the account settings of facebook there is a option to remove from all active logins. So that we can logout from all the system who logged into the same account.

Comment: My sister followed the advices from https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/forget-to-log-out-help-is-on-the-way/425136200765 and it worked. Does it work for you?

Comment: When she's logged in to Facebook.  Go into Settings > Security.  1) She can be notified when someone logs into her account.  2)  Click on "Where You're Logged In".  Then click on End Activity for each connection.  This will kill any of her sessions as well.  Have her log in and change the password again, and make sure it's a secure password.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that her passwords are being synced through the browser. If this is true then even if she changes her password it can be updated on any synced device (convenient for someone who is not in this situation). To remedy this, she will need to change her browser sync settings and password, then change her facebook password (and others) again.

I personally use Firefox and I know the sync settings need to be specially setup, but I believe it is easy to do this even by accident if you are using Chrome, though I may be wrong.